# Creating a Custom Receiver - my App ID doesn't work with Cactool v.2

Tags: google-cast

I'm following the https://developers.google.com/cast/codelabs/cast-receiver tutorial, but after registering my basic receiver with my own App ID, my app isn't castable in the Cactool v.2 sender simulator (in step 8 of the tutorial).

I'm using a Chromecast with Google TV HD device, and it works with the default App ID (CC1AD845) but when I switch to mine, the cast button no longer appears.

I've whitelisted my device and I've registered my App.

Testing my device via the Cactool works fine with the default App ID.

I was able to get a cow-orker to successfully test it on a 2nd or 3rd Generation Chromecast, but the Cactool  (https://casttool.appspot.com/cactool/?appId=CC1AD845) doesn't work locally with my custom, unpublished App Id.

Is there a version of the Cactool that DOES work with Generation 4 Chromecast devices, or is there a Sender utility other than Cactool v2 that can be used to test/develop?

**Update**:  I purchased a 3rd Generation Chromecast device and was able to get the Cactool v2 to work (after registering it and restarting it) so the issue is definitely with the 4th generation device.